# Block loading mixed active content

Tags: magento-1.7, contact-us

When i load the site with https, the browser informed that "Block loading mixed active content". I see the view source, many of the url in http. But i used

```
<a href="{{store direct_url="contact-us"}}">Contact Us</a>
```

why when accessing https, the url is not change to https?

Comment: This is not mixed content. All links in the anchors can be whatever they want. Mixed content means, loaded content wird different protocols, e.g. `<script>`, CSS and `<img>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Firebug (Firefox) or the Chrome Dev Tools (Chrome) to check all the loaded sources on your page.

[image]

Check for a source that is loaded over HTTP instead of HTTPS. This could be a CSS, image or Javascript file as @abian-blechschmidt stated or it might be a Twitter or Facebook share button that is using the HTTP protocol.

Comment: Any tracking scripts loaded on your website need to be removed from your page display in secure locations if the vendor isn't smart enough to have them load secure content on secure pages. We had to create a script loader for one that detected SSL and denied loading. Celebros of all companies, you'd think would know this. While this probably isn't the case, using the Chrome DEV tools was very helpful in weeding the issue out. Page components not loaded from https need scripts modified or templates repaired to be protocol agnostic.

Answer (score 4):

Tamil,

Each extension in Magento controls whether or not the links are secure. With Magento there are secure areas and insecure areas. By default url paths are insecure unless defined as secure.

Example: If you look in the core Mage Checkout config.xml you will find

```
<config>
...
    <frontend>
...
        <secure_url>
            <checkout_onepage>/checkout/onepage</checkout_onepage>
            <checkout_multishipping>/checkout/multishipping</checkout_multishipping>
        </secure_url>
...
```

This `<secure_url>` config key tells Magento that these urls are to be secure. So Magento will create the links using the `{{secure_base_url}}` from the Store Configuration in the Magento Backend, as the base url. It also protect the traffic by redirecting any calls to the insecure, to the secure url.

To Answer your question...
Mage Contacts doesn't use secure urls for the contact form. So, it will always use the insecure urls. If you want it to be secure, the contacts secure_url config needs to be added.

Comment: this is the correct answer in magento context.